# HTML 5 allows to place a block element inside an anchor tag. Is there a work around to make it so IE7 also support it?

Tags: html, internet-explorer-7, modernizr, html5boilerplate

I want to dig into html5, I have used html5boilerplate which has modernizr.js I wrote following code but it seems IE7 do not support it. What is the workaround for it using modernizr so it can work in IE7? I am not very familiar with html5, html5bp and modernizr.

```
<a href="/somlink">
  <img src="/img/someimage.jpg" alt="some image">
  <span>Some Caption</span>
  <h1>Some Heading<span class="subtext">Inside Anchor</span></h1>
</a>
```

Comment: I thought IE7 allowed you to do that anyway. What's happening when you do it?

Comment: Yes, it is showing and image is also click-able but it do not make other elements click-able

Comment: http://jsbin.com/ilojim/ For me, this is working in IE7. The `img`, the `span` and the `h1` are all clickable.

Comment: I have position:absolute for span and h1 so these can hover over the image. is it the reason?

Comment: @Blowski I am using modernizr and along with it I used ie7.js (infact ie9.js) in head section. All links are started rendering the value of href for example "Home http://www.somelink.com" why its happening any idea

Comment: Maybe this will help? http://groups.google.com/group/ie7-js/browse_thread/thread/90adea30f122c93?pli=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on comments above, this will work in IE7 without doing anything.

The problem is that you are using `position:absolute` on the `span` and `h1`. They are still clickable, but the cursor makes it look like they are not. Just add a `cursor:pointer` to get round this.

See: http://jsbin.com/ilojim/4/

Comment: It indeed works even on IE 7. HTML5 is just going to standardize common practice. But the real problem is: how do you convey the idea “this is a clickable link, and all of this constitutes one link” to the user? Browsers differ in how they render block-level content in links, and it is difficult to say how it *should* be styled.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela If it's obvious where the whole div should link, then it should be OK. For example, in the profile link underneath an answer, it _looks_ like the photo and the username will link to the profile. One link around the whole block should thus be OK.